# How to measure wave direction in 2D?

Tags: waves

The attached image shows a single state (edit: or rather, snapshot) of my system, which is a square sensor grid. While it is impossible to show using single images, the waves in this exceprt are travelling towards the center. For each of the points, I want to compute the x- and y-direction of the traveling wave.

Edit: The color codes displacement from equilibrium (red higher, blue lower)

[image: http://imgur.com/a/o7tbh]

Edit: Gradient
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Generally, it's impossible to define a wave direction in a specific point, as there may be two (or more) superposing waves passing through any point, each with its own direction.

Moreover, it may be impossible to tell how the wave will move, knowing only the displacements at a specific time (though that may depend on what is the wave equation) That is because in most systems, the wave equation is of the second order in time, which means that to solve it you need not only the initail displacements, but also the initial time derivative of the dsplacements.

Assuming that you know the time evolution of the wave, you may be able to identify the set of points at which the displacement has a specific value and analyze how these sets change. But as I said before, it's impossible to calculate from a still image of the wave.

Answer (score 0):

If the colours indicate different displacements from the equilibrium position then the locus of all points which are in phase (same colour) is called a wavefront.
The direction of motion of a wave is at right angles to the wavefront.

Comment: Yes, exactly.  Could you please elaborate on how to compute the wavefront in this case?

Comment: I am sorry but I can only say that by interpolation between the points you could generate a locus of constant displacement?  As to how you actually code this I suggest that you ask on the programming site.  This is exactly equivalent to having a map of spot electrical potential or height above sea level values and obtaining equipotential/contour lines from those spot values.  So perhaps a search in those area might fully answer your question?

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. Can I ask you another thing? Supposed I have the orthogonal of the wavefront, how do you get the actual direction? The orthogonal would be just a line (the orientation of the wave in 2D) but shouldn't the direction be a vector?

Comment: You might do it by using a bearing as per a compass.  From what you have written it will be pointing towards a point/small area at the centre.

Answer (score 0):

You should ascribe numerical values to each color (or, better, use the actual numerical values from the software used to build the image) and then perform "numerical differentiation" (Google it) to calculate the gradient of the function - there are several methods, and it is not easy to get decent accuracy. For what it's worth, to get smoother results, you may consider your numbers as a real function of a complex variable (x+iy) and calculate the gradient as a complex numerical derivative of the real function with respect to the complex variable averaged over 4 directions (along the abscissa, along the ordinate, and along the two diagonals).

Comment: I've done what you've suggested and it makes sense to proceed this way. However, I'm not sure how to sure how to include time, as I want to show that the waves travel (taking the gradient just shows me the slopes for a snapshot of the system). I've edited the original to include the results of my current step.

Comment: @JohnSmith: I am not sure you need gradient for that. You may just build an animation based on 3d graphs (displacement as a function of coordinates for different points in time).

Comment: Of course, but I'd rather want a single image. Basically, I want to create the same as the last figure (the one titled 'gradient') where all the tiny arrows point to the center.

Comment: @JohnSmith: But that would only be for one point in time. And anyway, you already have it. So what do you need?

Comment: Sorry I haven't been clear. I want the direction of travel, not the gradient of a snapshot of the wave, like this but in 2D: http://www.antonine-education.co.uk/Image_library/GCSE/Sound_01.gif

Comment: @JohnSmith: Crudely, you can do the following: calculate the gradient, and define the direction of motion of the wave in each point as follows: build a unit vector in the same or opposite direction as the gradient, choosing the direction ("same" or "opposite") in such a way that the vector is directed to the center.

Comment: @JohnSmith: Accuracy maybe low in the areas where the gradient is small, so you may wish to show the arrows only where the magnitude of the gradient exceeds some value.